# Python recursive dictionary value finder returns None

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

I am working with multiple dictionaries which all have different depths and I am looking for the key `"values"` in all of them. I am not very familiar with recursive functions, but for this problem I attempted to write one. According to my print statements, the function arrives at the key I'm looking for, but it returns `None`.

An example of such a dictionary is this:

```
d = {'key1': {'key2': {'values': [0, 1, 2]}}}
```

I wrote this function to find the key `"values"`, but the output is not what I expected:

```
def extract_key(dict_, key, path=[]):
    if not isinstance(dict_, dict):
        raise ValueError("went to deep")
    else:
        keys = list(dict_.keys()) # get all keys, list for indexing
        print("path:", path)
        print("keys:", keys)
        if key not in keys: # continue looking for key
            next_key = keys[0]
            print("next_key:", next_key)
            next_dict = dict_[next_key] # look with first key of keys
            path.append(next_key)
            extract_key(next_dict, key, path)
        else: # found key, return values
            print("out:", key)
            return dict_[key]

output = extract_key(d, "values")
print(output)
```

Output:

```
path: []
keys: ['key1']
next_key: key1
path: ['key1']
keys: ['key2']
next_key: key2
path: ['key1', 'key2']
keys: ['values']
out: values
None
```

Why does it not return the list I'm looking for but also not an error, and how do I fix this?

Comment: You call your recursive function, but never return its value (`return extract_key(...`)

Comment: [Off-topic] Also note that you probably do not want to use the `path=[]` default argument: it will be bound at function definition and not at call time, meaning you will use the same list in successive calls without explicit `path` argument. See for example https://florimond.dev/en/posts/2018/08/python-mutable-defaults-are-the-source-of-all-evil/

Answer (score 0):

You can *fix/simplify* your code this way :

```
# without the prints
def extract_key(obj, key):
    for k, v in obj.items():
        if k==key and isinstance(v, list):
            yield v
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            yield from extract_key(v, key)
```

Output :

```
print(*extract_key(d, "values")) # [0, 1, 2] [6, 7, 8]

from itertools import chain # to flatten the list
print(*chain.from_iterable(extract_key(d, "values"))) # 0 1 2 6 7 8
```

Used input :

```
d = {
    'key1': {
        'values': [0, 1, 2],
        'key2': {
            'fake_values': [3, 4, 5],
        },
        'key3': {
            'key4': {
                'values': [6, 7, 8]
            }
        }
    }
}
```